# Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

this was my reducer that worked great:

```
    const rootReducer   =   createStoreWithMiddleware(combineReducers({
        companies: companies,
        brands: brands,
        login: login,
        chat: chat,
        banners: banners,
        sessions: sessions,
        settings: settings,
        statistics: statistics
}));
```

i want my system to be modular so i tried change it to:

```
    const rootReducer   =   createStoreWithMiddleware(combineReducers({
    chatModule: {
        companies: companies,
        brands: brands,
        login: login,
        chat: chat,
        banners: banners,
        sessions: sessions,
        settings: settings,
        statistics: statistics
    }
}));
```

then i get this error in the browser:

```
Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.
```

this is the whole file code:

```
    import {combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import {login, chat, chatClick, banners, sessions, companies, settings, statistics, brands} from '../actions/actions'

const createStoreWithMiddleware =   applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);

const rootReducer   =   createStoreWithMiddleware(combineReducers({
    chatModule: {
        companies: companies,
        brands: brands,
        login: login,
        chat: chat,
        banners: banners,
        sessions: sessions,
        settings: settings,
        statistics: statistics
    }
}));

export default rootReducer;
```

companies, brands, login, etc... are exported function...

Answer (score 3):

As said in error message you should pass to `combineReducers` object whose values are **reducers**. You passed an object whose value is an **object** (`{companies: companies,brands: brands, ...}`)

`combineReducers` returns reducer itself so you can do:

```
const rootReducer = createStoreWithMiddleware(combineReducers({
  chatModule: combineReducers({
    companies: companies,
    brands: brands,
    login: login,
    chat: chat,
    banners: banners,
    sessions: sessions,
    settings: settings,
    statistics: statistics
  })
})
```